# Is there a way to crop an SVG using java-batik?

Tags: java, svg, crop, batik

I'm trying to load an SVG from the file System, crop it and save the cropped part again using java-batik.

After successfully loading my SVG as an "SVGDocument", I'm experiencing some issues trying to crop it.

Here's what I tried:

I found the interface "[PadRable](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/image/renderable/PadRable.html)" that according to his documentation is basically a "crop".

> Pads image to the given Rectangle (the rect may be smaller than the image in which case this is actually a crop).

Then I found the implementing class "[PadRable8Bit](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/image/renderable/PadRable8Bit.html)" but I got stuck to the following issue:

here's the constructor: *PadRable8Bit(Filter src, Rectangle2D padRect, PadMode padMode)*

to what I understand "src" should be what I need to crop, but I'm not able to instantiate correctly an object implementing or indirectly extending "Filter", also looked for a factory into source files without success.

Can someone help me? Am I on the right way or is there a better one to crop an SVG?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your exact use case is but as its a vector graphic, could you get away with change the viewport?

Comment: your suggestion was very helpful, once done I will post what I did as an Answer. thank you

Comment: Glad to have been of help